# jquery string replacement?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following mal formed html on my page after parsing an xml feed using curl:

```
<div class="rssfeed">
    <link> 
    http://example.com/cp/?(string_of_numbers)
    <a href="http://example.com/cp/?(same_string_of_numbers)">example</a>
</div>
```

where `<link>` has no closing tag and where the last string of numbers changes dynamically, I need to remove these mal formed  elements and it's first preceeding text node keeping the href completely so i was hoping to be able to search for a string beginning with http:// example.com/cp/? that is a direct child of  link only, i was hoping to achieve this like so:

```
jQuery('<link>:regex(^[*])').remove();
```

Using [james padolsey's regex](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) or any other method,  have tried the following but to no avail:

```
var reg = /\<link>.*\<a/;
jQuery(".rssfeed .rssfeed <link>").filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).text().match(reg);  
}).html(function(i,h) { 
    var nr = h.match(reg);
    jQuery(this).after(nr[0]);
    return h.replace(reg,'');
});
```

and this:

```
// Get the product number that lies between [ ] marks from all div elements
jQuery('.rssfeed .rssfeed:contains('<link>'+*+')').html(function() { 

//Look for the wildcard string and save it to a variable. how can I search within the string?!
        var $finalstring = jQuery(this).search('<link>'+*+');

//remove it from the string
jQuery(this).replace($finalstring, '');

    });
```

but nothing seems to work. 
could anyone help?
UPDATE: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYwk9/2/)

Comment: That's not how jQuery selectors work.

Comment: i know but that doesn't help, I do belive that in theory this is possible with the regex plugin but not sure.

Comment: *where `<link>` has no closing tag* — since the end tag for link elements is forbidden in HTML … that isn't a problem.

Comment: technically it wouldn't be a problem if the <link tag was formed correctly and self closing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
$('.rssfeed').contents().filter(function(){
  return !$(this).is('a,h1,p');
}).remove();
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/kYwk9/4/

Comment: ok thats good but i think my question is mal formed by div .rss feed has more elements in it such as h1 elements etc I'll put a fiddle together...

Comment: added a fiddle that is a little more acurate to what i have.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all rssfeed divs and replace them with divs and leaving only valid child tags:

```
$(".rssfeed").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($("<div></div>").addClass("rssfeed").append($("> *:not(link)", $(this))));
    });
```

See updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSV4B/